# Assign multiple values from subscribe object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an object with two simple numbers and then a list of objects:

```
export class Lineup {
  players: Player[];
  fantasypoints: number;
  salary: number;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

I hit a service to populate it with a post (I add in some players and get back a lineup from it:

```
public postLineup(players): Observable < Lineup > {
  return this.http.post <Lineup>(`${API_URL}/optimize`, JSON.stringify(players));
}
```

This POST returns the data fine and as far as I can tell it will correctly populate the JSON into the Lineup object.

However in my app.component when I try to assign these values into component variables so I can actually use the data. I can't seem to get the assignments to work.

```
onClickOptimize() {
  this.apiService.postLineup(this.playerSource.data)
    .subscribe(lineupreturned => {
      this.lineupSource = new MatTableDataSource(lineupreturned.players);
      this.salary = lineupreturned.salary;
      this.fantasypoints = lineupreturned.fantasypoints;
      this.displaylineup = true;
      console.log("component output:"), console.log(lineupreturned);
    });
}
```

The `console.log` of `lineupreturned` actually shows an object and it is populated. However, if you were to log `this.salary` or any other variable it comes back as `undefined`. I cannot for the life of me understand why none of these variables are getting populated.

**EDIT: with lineupreturned variable result from console.log:**

```
null: Array(1) [Object]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0) [, …]
0: Object {fantasypoints: 324.15, players: Array(8), salary: 48800}
fantasypoints: 324.15
players: Array(8) [Object, Object, Object, …]
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0) [, …]
0: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Ray", …}
1: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Clearlove", …}
2: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Scout", …}
3: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Hope", …}
4: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Meiko", …}
5: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "SnowFlower", …}
6: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Arce", …}
7: Object {_max_exposure: null, _projected_ownership: null, first_name: "Infinity eSports", …}
salary: 48800
__proto__: Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
```

Comment: Why are all of those assignments one logical line? Also, where (and *when*) are you seeing those values as undefined?

Comment: The page loads up some players. Then you can select some players and click a button "Optimize". On that button click onClickOptimize is run. EDIT: It is when I click Optimize and the POST response comes back that I see the lineupreturned populated but the variables I'm assigning remain undefined. As to why they're in one logical line, I suppose no good reason other than I was trying to debug why I haven't been able to bind anything from the subscription result. Plus I need to bind the players in the Lineup object to a MatTableDataSource and not leave it as a player list.

Comment: why we have , at the end of each line instead ';'?

Comment: I'm bad at typescript I guess? I have changed those to semi-colons and it did not change anything. I suspect from the first question asked that I'm trying to do something with data that does not exist yet? I have read many SO posts on this but the fact that console.log shows data in the lineupreturned but I cannot seem to get it assigned to any other variables is what I can't figure out.

Comment: Please add the sample of `lineupreturned` that you're getting from your API.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I have done so in the original comment.

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(lineupreturned))`; it makes it much easier to read than a copy paste from the console's output of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues I noticed:

Here you're doing `JSON.stringify(players)` which isn't really required.

```
public postLineup(players): Observable < Lineup > {
  return this.http.post <Lineup>(`${API_URL}/optimize`, JSON.stringify(players));
}
```

So this should have been:

```
public postLineup(players): Observable < Lineup > {
  return this.http.post <Lineup>(`${API_URL}/optimize`, players);
}
```

Another thing is,

```
onClickOptimize() {
  this.apiService.postLineup(this.playerSource.data)
    .subscribe(lineupreturned => {
      const actualResponse = lineupreturned[0];
      this.lineupSource = new MatTableDataSource(actualResponse.players);
      this.salary = actualResponse.salary;
      this.fantasypoints = actualResponse.fantasypoints;
      this.displaylineup = true;
      console.log("component output:"), console.log(lineupreturned);
    });
}
```

Here, you're using `new MatTableDataSource(lineupreturned.players)` which might have thrown an error.

So you might want to place a breakpoint over there to see the actual value of `lineupreturned` and also check on the console for any errors.

### UPDATE

From your `console.log` output, looks like the actual response is an array with just one object inside it. This object will contain things like `fantasypoints`, `players`, and `salary`.

So change your subscribe code as I've updated.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. I have removed the stringify. I also removed the MatTableDataSource entirely just to see if that made a different. It did not. For instance if I do this.salary = lineupreturned.salary, this.salary remains undefined. However console.log(lineupreturned) below it returns a fully populated object... This is driving me nuts. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check. TL;DR; `lineupreturned` is an `Array` with just a single `Object`. This `Object` will have things like `fantasypoints`, `players`, and `salary`